# Caching a redirect to a static image in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra, cache-control

I have a Sinatra route for displaying a status image. While this simple solution works, I run into caching issues:

```
get '/stream/:service/:stream_id.png' do
  # Building image_url omitted

  redirect image_url
end
```

What is a proper way to handle the caching here, to set a max TTL? These images will be embedded on other sites, otherwise I could simply link straight to the images I redirect to.

The problem is that it generates an URL like `site.com/image.png` which in turn redirects elsewhere -- but it's `site.com/image.png` that is considered cached by the browser, so it won't check if it's updated.

I've experimented a bit with Cache-Control headers, but I have yet to find a solution.

I'm open for other solutions if this method is completely boneheaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the Cache-Control on a per route basis:

```
get '/stream/:service/:stream_id.png' do
  # Building image_url omitted
  response['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  redirect image_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Sinatra's `expires` method:

```
# Set the Expires header and Cache-Control/max-age directive. Amount
# can be an integer number of seconds in the future or a Time object
# indicating when the response should be considered "stale". The remaining
# "values" arguments are passed to the #cache_control helper:
#
#   expires 500, :public, :must_revalidate
#   => Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=60
#   => Expires: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 08:50:17 GMT
```

Or the `cache_control` method:

```
# Specify response freshness policy for HTTP caches (Cache-Control header).
# Any number of non-value directives (:public, :private, :no_cache,
# :no_store, :must_revalidate, :proxy_revalidate) may be passed along with
# a Hash of value directives (:max_age, :min_stale, :s_max_age).
#
#   cache_control :public, :must_revalidate, :max_age => 60
#   => Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=60
#
# See RFC 2616 / 14.9 for more on standard cache control directives:
# http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.9.1
```

**Sinatra Documentation (as of 1.4.6 release)**

- https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L440
- https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L469